# Eclipse Project Explorer not working on fedora 20 and eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, fedora

Under fedora 20 and eclipse luna - the project explorer doesn't show classes underneath cpp and h files.

Running on my home machine under lubuntu - it works fine.

Comment: Do you have C/C++ functionality installed? Are whatever Content Providers it contributes enabled?

Comment: I installed the CDT if that's what you're asking.  Where do I look for proper enabling of content providers?

Comment: From the view's local menu, you would choose `Customize View...` and then turn them on in the `Content` tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove my projects and then

Import > c/c++ > existing code as makefile project

And now they are showing up.  I don't know what was causing the trouble.